# Does Eclipse plugin have to be written in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jvm-languages

I read some tutorials about making Eclipse plugins, but every text was just about Java coding. Does it really have to be Java or there is some way to write a plugin in some other JVM language such as Scala or Clojure?

Comment: The Scala Eclipse Plugin itself is written in Scala. From the outside it's all Java classes, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use all languages that are based on JVM. You need to simply add a dependency jar (e.g. Scala dependency).

Tested live, so it must work!

Answer (score 2):

Current version of [Scala IDE](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide) is written in Scala